# Write dictionary in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, stop-words, reader

I would like to add values from all the dictionaries I created in my Python script in a CSV file during the execution of my code, so that at the end I would have something like this :

File at beginning:

```
id;Verbatim;score
15;je suis monter à la boulangerie;4
44;tu es méchant;5
45;je te hais et la foret enchanté est belle de milles faux et les jeunes filles sont assises au bor de la mer;7
47;je ne comprends pas la vie et je suis perdue, aide moi stp maman je suis perdue tu es ma seule amie et je t'aime;8
```

csv file at the end :  (for the simple way; I would like to add this columns in the existing file)

```
id;Verbatim;score;**d_tag;d_lemma;d_filtered_words**
15;Je suis monter à , la boulangerie;4;['Je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'suis\tVER:pres\tsuivre|être', 'monter\tVER:infi\tmonter', 'à\tPRP\tà', ',\tPUN\t,', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'boulangerie\tNOM\tboulangerie'];['je', 'suivre|être', 'monter', 'à', ',', 'le', 'boulangerie'];['monter', 'boulangerie']
44;Tu es ? méchant;5;['Tu\tPRO:PER\ttu', 'es\tVER:pres\têtre', '?\tSENT\t?', 'méchant\tNOM\tméchant'];['tu', 'être', '?', 'méchant'];['être', 'méchant']
45;Je te hais et la Foret enchantée est belle de milles faux et les jeunes filles sont assises au bor de la mer;7;['Je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'te\tPRO:PER\tte', 'hais\tVER:pres\thaïr', 'et\tKON\tet', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'Foret\tNAM\tForet', 'enchantée\tVER:pper\tenchanter', 'est\tVER:pres\têtre', 'belle\tADJ\tbeau', 'de\tPRP\tde', 'milles\tNOM\tmille', 'faux\tADJ\tfaux', 'et\tKON\tet', 'les\tDET:ART\tle', 'jeunes\tADJ\tjeune', 'filles\tNOM\tfille', 'sont\tVER:pres\têtre', 'assises\tVER:pper\tasseoir', 'au\tPRP:det\tau', 'bor\tNOM\tbor', 'de\tPRP\tde', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'mer\tNOM\tmer'];['je', 'te', 'haïr', 'et', 'le', 'Foret', 'enchanter', 'être', 'beau', 'de', 'mille', 'faux', 'et', 'le', 'jeune', 'fille', 'être', 'asseoir', 'au', 'bor', 'de', 'le', 'mer'];['haïr', 'Foret', 'enchanter', 'être', 'beau', 'mille', 'faux', 'jeune', 'fille', 'être', 'asseoir', 'bor', 'mer']
47;Je ne Comprends pas la vie et je ? suis perdue aide moi stp maman je suis perdue tu es ma seule amie et je t'aime;8;['Je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'ne\tADV\tne', 'Comprends\tVER:pres\tcomprendre', 'pas\tADV\tpas', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'vie\tNOM\tvie', 'et\tKON\tet', 'je\tPRO:PER\tje', '?\tSENT\t?', 'suis\tVER:pres\tsuivre|être', 'perdue\tVER:pper\tperdre', 'aide\tNOM\taide', 'moi\tPRO:PER\tmoi', 'stp\tVER:simp\tstp', 'maman\tNOM\tmaman', 'je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'suis\tVER:pres\tsuivre|être', 'perdue\tVER:pper\tperdre', 'tu\tPRO:PER\ttu', 'es\tVER:pres\têtre', 'ma\tDET:POS\tmon', 'seule\tADJ\tseul', 'amie\tNOM\tami', 'et\tKON\tet', 'je\tPRO:PER\tje', ""t'\tPRO:PER\tte"", 'aime\tVER:pres\taimer'];['je', 'ne', 'comprendre', 'pas', 'le', 'vie', 'et', 'je', '?', 'suivre|être', 'perdre', 'aide', 'moi', 'stp', 'maman', 'je', 'suivre|être', 'perdre', 'tu', 'être', 'mon', 'seul', 'ami', 'et', 'je', 'te', 'aimer'];['comprendre', 'vie', 'perdre', 'aide', 'stp', 'maman', 'perdre', 'être', 'seul', 'ami', 'aimer']
```

Full code :

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import os
import sys, argparse
import subprocess
import pprint
import csv
from itertools import islice
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    from treetaggerwrapper import TreeTagger, make_tags
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")

from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict

#export le lexique de sentiments
pickle_in = open("dict_pickle", "rb")
dico_lexique = pickle.load(pickle_in)

# extraction colonne verbatim
d = {}

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        try:
            d[token[0]] = token[1]
        except:
            print(line)
print(d)

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')
d_tag = {}
for key, val in d.items(): 
        newvalues = tagger.tag_text(val)
        d_tag[key] = newvalues
#print(d_tag)

#lemma dictionary
d_lemma = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in d_tag.items():
    for p in v:
        parts = p.split('\t')
        try:
            d_lemma[k].append(parts[2])
        except:
            print(parts)
print(d_lemma)                          

#filtered words
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('french'))
d_filtered_words = defaultdict(list)

d_filtered_words = {k: [w for w in l if w not in stopWords and w.isalpha()] for k, l in d_lemma.items()}
print(d_filtered_words)

#writing tags in the dictionary 
with open("sortie.csv", "w") as output:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, "w")
    for k, v in d_tag.items():
        writer.writerow(k)
        writer.writerow(v)
```

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to show a worked example. i.e. show a few sample input CSV rows and underneath what the expected output CSV file should look like.

Comment: @MartinEvans I re-edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find it easier to use just the `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` to read and write your files. First read the file into `rows` which would be a list of the rows. This approach means it is not necessary to keep track of `id` as a key in a big dictionary. Instead, the rows are processed one row at a time.

Next take the the second element from each row (`verbatim`) and calculate your tags, lemmas and filtered words. As you want these written in a list style, convert each list to a string using `str()`. These three lists can then be added to the end of the existing `row` (using `extend()`) and this can then be written to your output file:

```
import csv

# Read the CSV file into a list of lists
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';')
    header = next(csv_input)
    rows = list(csv_input)

# Create the output CSV file
with open('sortie.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')
    header.extend(['d_tag', 'd_lemma', 'd_filtered_words'])
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    # Process the data, one row at a time
    for row in rows:
        if row:  # skip empty rows
            verbatim = row[1]

            # Calculate d_tag, d_lemma, d_filtered_words
            tags = ['a\tb\tc', 'd\te\tf']
            lemmas = ['1\t2\t3', '4\t5\t6']
            filtered_words = ['u\tv\tw\t', 'x\ty\tz']

            row.extend([str(tags), str(lemmas), str(filtered_words)])
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your answer but could you i get an error :    verbatim = row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That implies you have blank lines somewhere in your CSV file (which could be the last line). A simple `if row:` test can be added.